# Multiple delete ListView and reflect in sqlite db

Tags: android

I am trying to delete on long clicking multiple items in `ListView`. I have included the code for multiple items delete. But the item is not deleted. Please help me to delete the item from list and reflect it in db.

`ListViewAdapter` is my adapter class for `ListView`.
`all_memories_getter_setter` is my getter/setter for `ListViewitems`.
`All_memories` is my java class where I am including code for multiple items delete.

Here is my listview adapter code:

```
package com.example.intel.personaldiary.Adapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.intel.personaldiary.All_memories;
import com.example.intel.personaldiary.R;
import com.example.intel.personaldiary.all_memories_getter_setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>list;
Activity activity;

/////**/////
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public  ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>list)
{
    super();
    mSelectedItemsIds= new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


/////**///////
public void remove(all_memories_getter_setter object){
    list.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<all_memories_getter_setter> getall_memories_getter_setter(){
    return list;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position){
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));

}
public void removeSelection(){
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position , boolean value){
    if(value){
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    }else{
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
public int getSelectedCount(){
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}
public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds(){
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}



public  class Viewholder
{
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    Viewholder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_all_memories_listview, null);
        holder = new Viewholder();

        holder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_date);
        holder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        holder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtFirst.setText("" + list.get(position).getDate());
    holder.txtSecond.setText("" + list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtThird.setText("" + list.get(position).getContent());
return  convertView;
}


}
```

Here is my getter setter class code:

```
package com.example.intel.personaldiary;
public class all_memories_getter_setter {
int id;
String date;
String title;
String content;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getContent() { return content; }

public void setContent(String content) { this.content = content; }

}
```

Here's my multiple delete code class:

```
public class All_memories extends Activity {
ListView listview;
ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>list;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_memories1);


    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmemories);
    populateList();
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

/////multiple delete on clicking listview///////

    listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                              int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            // Capture total checked items
            final int checkedCount = listview.getCheckedItemCount();

            // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
            adapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
                    // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {

                            all_memories_getter_setter selecteditem = (all_memories_getter_setter) adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                       getContentResolver().delete(DataProvider.WRITE_URI, DataProvider.ID + '=' + list.get(i).getId(), null);

                            System.out.println("##############values of ss" + list.get(i).getId());
                            // Remove selected items following the ids
                            adapter.remove(selecteditem);

                            populateList();

                        }
                    }

                    final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(All_memories.this, list);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.removeSelection();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });

    /////multiple delete on clicking listview///////


/////////////////////////////retrieve from db and display in listview

private void populateList() {       System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");

    Cursor cs;
    list = new ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>();
    SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    Cursor cursor;
    mydb=getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DataProvider.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    cursor=mydb.rawQuery("Select * from "+DataProvider.TBL_WRITE+"",null);
    System.out.println("cursor"+cursor.getCount());

    cs = getContentResolver().query(DataProvider.WRITE_URI, null, null, null, null);
        System.out.println("$$count is" + cs.getCount());

    System.out.println("size of list" + list.size());
    System.out.println("ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
    list = new ArrayList<all_memories_getter_setter>();
    // Cursor cs = getContentResolver().query(DataProvider.REM_URI, null, null, null, null);
    System.out.println("ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    //cs.moveToFirst();
    while (cs.moveToNext()) {

        int a;

        int id = cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.ID));
        System.out.println("**id" + id);
        String str_date = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.DATE));
        String str_title = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.TITLE));
        String str_content = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.CONTENT));
        //String str_spi = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.TYPE));
        //String str_remi = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.REM));

        System.out.println("$$name is" + str_date);
        System.out.println("$$name is" + str_title);
        System.out.println("$$name is" + str_content);
        //System.out.println("$$name$$ is" + str_remi);

        Log.e("NAME_MAIN", str_date);
        all_memories_getter_setter  all_memories_getter_setter = new  all_memories_getter_setter();
       // all_memories_getter_setter.setId(id);
        //details.setName(str_name);
        all_memories_getter_setter.setDate(str_date);
        all_memories_getter_setter.setTitle(str_title);
        all_memories_getter_setter.setContent(str_content);
        //details.setRemtype(str_remi);
        // details.setRem(str_rem);
        list.add( all_memories_getter_setter);

        System.out.println("temp1 values" + list);
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), THIRD_COLUMN, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }               }

/////////////retrieve from db and display in listview////////
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview

Comment: This is not what I want. I have to delete from listview and also from db. I have included the code for deleting. But the items in the listview are not deleted.

Comment: Why you are resetting final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(All_memories.this, list); listview.setAdapter(adapter); list data is not modified. You need to remove these 2 lines from your code

Comment: list items deleted. bt i again open that page, the deleted items are still there.

Comment: Possibly your URI is creating a problem.